# Run Test.class, but I get Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I want create testing AnnManagerTest.java, but get an error after execution:Failed to load ApplicationContext.

This is my code:

1.SpringConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.*"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new LoginInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("MyKMPersistenceUnit");
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.model"});
    em.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

em.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:/persistenceXXX.xml");
    return em;
}


@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}


@Bean
public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", DerbyTenSevenDialect.class.getName());
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    return props;
}


@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/KM");
    dataSource.setUsername("username");
    dataSource.setPassword("passwd");
    dataSource.setInitialSize(10);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
    return dataSource;
}


@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    jpaTransactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}


@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}


@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}


@Bean
public SpringContextUtil springContextUtil() {
    return new SpringContextUtil();
}
```

}

2.SpringContextUtil.java

```
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      SpringContextUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }


  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
      return applicationContext;
  }

  public static Object getBean(String name) throws BeansException {
      return applicationContext.getBean(name);
  }
}
```

3.AnnManagerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringConfiguration.class}, loader =  AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AnnManagerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Test
public void testDoModify() throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext();
    AnnouncementHeaderService service = (AnnouncementHeaderService) ctx.getBean("announcementHeaderService");
    AnnouncementHeader announcementHeader = new AnnouncementHeader();
    announcementHeader.setAnnID(40);
    announcementHeader = service.findByOne(announcementHeader);
}
}
```

This is my exception:

```
2016-07-27 23:15:03 WARN  GenericApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
2016-07-27 23:15:03 INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:481 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'MyKMPersistenceUnit'
2016-07-27 23:15:03 ERROR TestContextManager:231 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4f6ee6e4] to prepare test instance [com.controller.system.AnnManagerTest@62c6db99]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Who can tell me what? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the following is my solution:
In Test Packages, directory:com/controller/system, have three java

```
1. AnnManagerTest.java

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaTestConfig.class,     SpringContextUtil.class})
public class AnnManagerTest  {

@Test
public void testDoModify() throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext();
    AnnouncementHeaderService service = (AnnouncementHeaderService) ctx.getBean("announcementHeaderService");
    List<AnnouncementHeader> list = service.findAll();
    assertNotNull(list);
}
}

2.JpaTestConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaTestConfig {

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("MyTestPU");
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.model"});
    em.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", DerbyTenSevenDialect.class.getName());
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    return props;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/KM");
    dataSource.setUsername("username");
    dataSource.setPassword("passwd");
    dataSource.setInitialSize(10);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    jpaTransactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public SpringContextUtil springContextUtil() {
    return new SpringContextUtil();
}
}

3.SpringContextUtil.java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.model.*"})
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext; 

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    SpringContextUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}

public static Object getBean(String name) throws BeansException {
    return applicationContext.getBean(name);
}
}
```